# Save an array with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an array. Now I save it to the database:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $link = ['http://localhost.loca/image/img-1627019138.jpg'];

    $product = new Product();
    $product->link = $link;
    $product->save();
}
```

And it gives such error:

> Array to string conversion

I want to save it to the database in the form:

```
['http://localhost.loca/image/img-1627019138.jpg']
```

Because it has a lot of links so it has to be saved as an array in the field.

Comment: Do you have single dimensional array?

Comment: typically mysql do not support complex data type.so if your want to save array to database,you could use json_encode() to convert array to string

Comment: Any update?.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql does not yet support storing such complex values. Maybe you do it this way :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $link = ['http://localhost.loca/image/img-1627019138.jpg'];
    $product = new Product();
    $product->link = json_encode($link);
    $product->save();
}
```

If when saving to mysql there is an error :

```
[\'http:\/\/localhost.loca\/image\/img-1627019138.jpg\']
```

Then you can use : `json_encode($link, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you are trying to save an `array` in a `text` field... You have to change your column to be able to store an array. It should be a text column or json (depends on database) and you also have to [`cast`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) it to `array`.

Give us more information so we can help you do so...

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it this way.

A product *has many* links to it.

Use [`one to many`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship in Laravel.

This will also ensure your database is at least in [`1st normal form`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

**Snippet:**

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $links = ['http://localhost.loca/image/img-1627019138.jpg','http://localhost.loca/image/img-1627019139.jpg'];

    $product = new Product();
    // add product name etc
    $product->save();


    // you can do the below once you have defined the relationship
    // assuming link_url is a column in links table
    $link_models = [];
    foreach($links as $link){
        $link_models[] = new App\Link(['link_url' => $link]);
    }
    $product->links()->saveMany($link_models);
}
```